# What do double brackets mean in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

What do the double brackets (and semicolon) stand for and how can I type them in jEdit?

```
lemma "[[ xs @ zs = ys @ xs; [] @ xs = [] @ [] ]] ==> ys = zs"
apply simp
done
```

Pasting this to jedit directly yields

```
Inner syntax error⌂
Failed to parse prop
```

but I see this being used `Tutorial on Isabelle/HOL` in https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2022/doc/tutorial.pdf section `3.1.5 Assumptions`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shorthand notation for

```
lemma "xs @ zs = ys @ xs ==> [] @ xs = [] @ [] ==> ys = zs"
apply simp
done
```

in general

```
[| P1; P2; ... ; Pn |] ==> C
```

denotes

```
P1 ==> P2 ==> ... ==> Pn ==> C
```

This is explained in `Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL` https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2022/doc/prog-prove.pdf at the end of section `2.1.1 Types, Terms and Formulas`

> To display implications in this style in Isabelle/jEdit you need to set Plugins >
> Plugin Options > Isabelle/General > Print Mode to “brackets” and restart.

Comment: Note that these are not simply `[[` and `]]`, but rather `⟦` and `⟧`. You can enter these in Isabelle/jEdit by typing `[|` and `|]`.